# how can i get the clock alarms in android

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, alarms

i want to get the alarm in the Clock Application in the mobile iam using the following code

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("content://com.android.deskclock/AlarmClock");
        Cursor c = mContext.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null,null);
        if (c != null) {
            String names[] = c.getColumnNames();
            for (String temp : names) {
                System.out.println(temp);

            }

            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    int i = 0;
                    for (int j = 0; j < c.getColumnCount(); j++) {
                    }
                } while (c.moveToNext());
            }
        }
```

iam getting the following Exception

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider 
com.android.deskclock.AlarmProvider from ProcessRecord{4162b268 
12999:com.genie9.gcloudbackup/10059} (pid=12999, uid=10059) that is not exported from uid 10011
```

does any one knows what is the permission that i have to use here? i have searched alot and couldn't find anything usefull, thanks for helping

Comment: Hi,I am facing the same issue.Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can set an alarm using Alarm class [see here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/AlarmClock.html)

or You can not access this uri. but you can use below code to set an alarm with Alarm Clock,

```
Intent i = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
    i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, 9);
    i.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, 37);
    startActivity(i);
```

You ll need to add permission in manifest given below

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
```

Comment: no i dont want to use intents and use the Alarm Clock Application, i want to read all the alarms set in the device not adding one, is there any way to do this?